# JWT token HTTP authorization RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, jwt

I am using `JWT auth token` in my site, when I try to use it with `HTTP Header` Authorization : Bearer Token it's blocked by `apache` but if I use query string ?token=xxx it worked, I've google it and tried to create .htaccess but it still doesnt work :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)

RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

How to make `.htaccess` to replace `HTTP Header` to be GET parameter

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
```

become

```
url?token=xxxx
```